# How to implement each item without using for loop inside the useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

What I'm trying to do is to add some attributes to the clients that I call from the backend.
I have done it use it the for loop, but the Axios function is inside the useEffect hook, and it caused me a lot of errors.

ClientList.js (errors)

```
export default function ClientList() {
  const [clinetlist, setClinetlist] = useState([]);
  const [clientlist, setClientlist] = useState(0);
  
 useEffect(() => {
    const clientParams =
      "?userName=" + currentClient "&clientId="
     
setClientlist([]);
    axios
      .get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_BACKEND_URL + "clients" + clientParams)
      .then((response) => {

        response.data.forEach(function (item) {
          let newListclient = {
            id: item.id,
            previewurl: item.clinet_preview,
            name: item.clinet_name,
            type: "type of client",
            description: "client description",
            status: "Ready",
          };
          setClientlist((oldClientlist) => [...oldClientlist, neClientitem]);
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, [count]);
```

Like this, every data that comes from the backend, I gave them the attributes by creating a forEach loop, but this caused me errors, bc of the useEffect render.

At this moment the code is like this which doesn't have any errors:

ClientList.js (no errors)

```
export default function ClientList() {
  const [clinetlist, setClinetlist] = useState([]);
  const [clientlist, setClientlist] = useState(0);
  
 useEffect(() => {
    const clientParams =
      "?userName=" + currentClient "&clientId="
     
setClientlist([]);
    axios
      .get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_BACKEND_URL + "clients" + clientParams)
      .then((response) => {

        const {data} = response;
        setClientlist(data)
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, [count]);
```

What I'm trying to do is to make the for loop like in the (ListClients(with errors)), but not inside the useEffect hook. Want to assign every data that comes from backend with those attributes `newListclient`.

How can I do it?

Comment: What is count? Is it a state or some data from backened!

Comment: it's for another purpose, to count each new data, it doesn't affect nothing  in both codes

Comment: What are the errors? can you print errors here?

Comment: Is there a way to make the for loop outside the useEffect ?

Comment: I don't understand, why you are looping through response. Instead the second approach is fine with little tweaking   setClientlist([...clientList , ...data])

Comment: There is no need of loop unless you are filtering some indexes. Otherwise you are good to go with  setClientlist([...clientList , ...data])

Comment: the idea is the ```newListclient `` attributes to assign for every data that comes from the backend, and i thought to use a for loop for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242480/discussion-between-zani123-and-wasif-ali).

Answer (score 0):

You have added dependency in useEffect for count.
Make another useEffect with no dependencies and place your code inside it and use the logic below as your logic has some issues.

```
export default function ClientList() {
  const [clinetlist, setClinetlist] = useState([]);
  const [clientlist, setClientlist] = useState(0);
  useEffect(()=>{
         const clientParams =
  "?userName=" + currentClient "&clientId="
 
       setClientlist([]);
axios
  .get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_BACKEND_URL + "clients" + clientParams)
  .then((response) => {

    let finalCustom=response.data.map(function (item) {
     
      return {...item, id: item.id,
        previewurl: item.clinet_preview,
        name: item.clinet_name,
        type: "type of client",
        description: "client description",
        status: "Ready",}
    });
    setClientlist(finalCustom)
  
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
 },[])
 useEffect(() => {
   
  }, [count]);
```